# Overlapping React Navigation Header in react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

Im working in a react native app, for my navigation, I used react-navigation 4, In one of the screens I want to Overlap the react-navigation header with a card component, On android, it's working fine but on iOS I can't get it to work even though I set the card zIndex to a big number it's always hidden by the react-navigation header.
here is the code for my component :

```
<View style={global.container}>
                <View style={styles.info}>
                    <View style={styles.card}>
                        <Image style={styles.image} source={app.appLogo} />
                    </View>
                </View>
<View>
```

and this is the CSS :

```
card:{
    padding:0,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor:"#fff",
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -70,
    zIndex:99,
    elevation:5
 
  },
```

Display on android:

[image]

Display on iOS:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please add zIndex to parent view. In iOS, the zIndex doesn't work for nested parentView. You need to make the parentView has high zIndex, and then target View again.

```
.container {
   zIndex:101
}
.info {
   zIndex:100
}
```